# Bootstrap modules using Zend Framework 1.8

Tags: zend-framework

I'm trying to figure out how to implement a modular structure with autoloader and Zend_Application.

I've got an structure that goes ok, but with the last commit to the tag 1.8 stop working.

[Can anybody try this code and see what's happened?](https://sites.google.com/site/jorgejorge/base.zip)

Thanks in advance

Comment: this is an issue. Reported to Zend: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-6545

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [autloading-modular-forms-models-in-zend-framework-18](http://think-robot.com/2009/07/autloading-modular-forms-models-in-zend-framework-18/)? I'd suggest just posting the content of your Bootstrap.php file here.